# Apache Configuration Location Match exclusion

Tags: regex, apache, configuration, proxypass

I have the following working rule on my Apache configuration relative to the "/":

> ProxyPass / http://foo.example.com/bar

but I want to exlude the location "/public" from the rule, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPass /public !

ProxyPass / http://foo.example.com/bar